# getText not available

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im working on a spark streaming program on Twitter data.
In my code,

```
object TwitterDataAnalysis {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if(args.length < 4) {
      System.err.println("Usage: TwitterPopularTags <consumer key> <consumer secret> " +
                          "<access token> <access token secret> [<filters>]")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
    val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)    
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)    
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter's trending HashTags").setMaster("local[2]")
    val ssc       = new StreamingContext(sparkConf,Seconds(5))
    val stream    = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)
    val tweets    = stream.flatMap(tweet => tweet.getText.split(" ")).filter(_.startsWith("#"))
  }
}
```

I haven't completed the program as Im getting an error with the line: **val tweets    = stream.flatMap(tweet => tweet.getText.split(" ")).filter(_.startsWith("#"))**.

It says: **value getText is not a member of type parameter T**
These are the dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
    <!-- Spark Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My Import statements:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import StreamingContext._
```

Can anyone tell what is the mistake Im doing ? I couldn't go further the bolded line as Im not getting functions after that. Is there anything I need to change in the code ?

Comment: It seems the compiler does not recognize the type of the streamed tweets. Could you add explicit type to `val stream: DStream[Status]`?

Comment: Tried like this:   ** val stream: DStream  = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)**
now this line is giving error: ** not found: type DStream **

Comment: Do you like to see any other settings or any other info from the project ?

Comment: its `DStream[twitter4j.Status]`, not just `DStream` (which is a type constructor, not a type)

Comment: I've put the statement like you said. Error is now with statement: val ssc       = new StreamingContext(sparkConf,Seconds(5))
Error message: bad symbolic reference. A signature in StreamingContext.class refers to term internal in package 
 org.apache.spark which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the 
 version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling 
StreamingContext.class.
I gave this import org.apache.spark but it is still same message. This import statement is marked error: import StreamingContext._